# How to schedule a dag to run a particular time of day of a month of a year. i.e., once

Tags: python-2.7, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm trying to execute a dag which needs to be run only once. So I placed the dag execution interval as '@once'. However, I'm getting the error as mentioned in this link -
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-1400

Now i'm trying to pass the exact date of execution as below:

```
default_args = {
'owner': 'airflow',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': datetime(2017,11,13),
'email': ['airflow@airflow.com'],
'email_on_failure': False,
'email_on_retry': False,
'retries': 1,
'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=5)
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='dagNameTest', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='12 09 13 11 2017',concurrency=1)
```

This is throwing error as:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/croniter/croniter.py", line 543, in expand
expr_format))
CroniterBadCronError: [12 09 13 11 2017] is not acceptable, out of range
```

Can someone help to resolve this.

Thanks,
Arjun

Answer (score 0):

You have 2017 in the "day of week" spot. Try [12 09 13 11 *](https://crontab.guru/#12_09_13_11_*). You are trying to set a "date" in a field "schedule *interval*". So technically this will schedule it for once a year. You can run it this way, and when it has finished, deactivate the DAG.

Answer (score 0):

Set a yearly interval for the minute, hour, day, month, and weekday number you want. I.E. `12 09 13 11 *`. Set your DAG's `start_date` and `end_date` before and after that date respectively, and it should run only once at that time.

```
default_args = {
'owner': 'airflow',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': datetime(2017,1,1),
'end_date': datetime(2017,12,31),
'email': ['airflow@airflow.com'],
'email_on_failure': False,
'email_on_retry': False,
'retries': 1,
'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=5)
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='dagNameTest', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='12 09 13 11 *',concurrency=1)
```

It's possible that since datetime can take your time you might set the start_date with the hour and minute and then use the `@once` schedule. But I haven't tried that myself.

```
default_args = {
'owner': 'airflow',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': datetime(2017,11,13,9,11),
'email': ['airflow@airflow.com'],
'email_on_failure': False,
'email_on_retry': False,
'retries': 1,
'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=5)
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='dagNameTest', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='@once',concurrency=1)
```